# C#: Am i validating filetype and using goto in a right manner?

Tags: c#

i have code to save a file like

```
SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
dialog.Filter = "Text files|*.txt";

SaveDialog:
if ((bool)dialog.ShowDialog()) {
    if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(dialog.FileName) != ".txt") {
        MessageBox.Show("You must select a .txt file");
        dialog.FileName = "";
        goto SaveDialog;
    }
    File.WriteAllText(dialog.FileName, txtEditor.Text);
}
```

i read that i should not use goto. i could use do/while and check that a valid extension was selected but that will add alot of unnecessary code. i find this neater. or is there a better/more correct way?

Comment: DialogResult cannot be cast to a boolean. :P

Comment: After so many years i have forgot about this key word.

Comment: @Siege: In WPF the result of `ShowDialog()` is a boolean

Comment: @jiewmeng: is this WPF or winforms?

Comment: @Matt Ellen: You're right (it's actually Nullable<bool>, which would explain the cast), for some reason I had assumed he was using WinForms.

Comment: this is WPF. i was a little shocked when i saw your comment @Siege, also wondering how come it works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
using (SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog())
{
    dialog.Filter = "Text files|*.txt";
    while(dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(dialog.FileName).ToLowerInvariant() != ".txt")
            MessageBox.Show("You must select a.txt file");
        else // file is ok
        {
            File.WriteAllText(dialog.FileName, txtEditor.Text);
            break;
        }
 }
```

Comment: I would upvote this answer if you didn't use `while (true)`. Put the next condition into the while-condition and it's good to go. If the user pressed cancel, he's not going to save the file anyway

Comment: You're absolutely right. Fixed it... also added the 'using' statement, as Bradley's answer suggests... good idea.

Comment: i am getting an error saying type used in using must be implicitly convertible to `System.IDisposable`. also there is no `DialogResult.OK`

Comment: My answer applies to winforms, in which SaveFileDialog implements IDisposable. I'm not familiar with WPF, so if this errors continues - simply remove the 'using' statement
Also, since this is WPF, change the 'while' condition to:
while ((bool)dialog.ShowDialog())

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest the following:

```
using (SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog()) {
    dialog.Filter = "Text files|*.txt";

    while (true) {
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
            if (!System.IO.Path.GetExtension(dialog.FileName).Equals(".txt", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) {
                MessageBox.Show("You must select a .txt file");
            }
            else {
                File.WriteAllText(dialog.FileName, txtEditor.Text);
                break; 
            }          
        }
        else break;
    }
}
```

While there are legitimate reasons for using the goto statement, in this case it can be avoided and replaced with a more readable solution.

Note also that you should not cast DialogResult (the return value of ShowDialog()) to bool.

Comment: +1 Though what's that bool valid doing in there ? :-)
Also nice point about using, so Dispose is called properly.

Comment: My mistake, carried forward from an earlier idea.

Comment: This is the solution I was going to suggest. But honestly, while I dislike seeing 'goto' when an alternative method exists, infinite loops don't offer much more in terms of readability.

Comment: I would still argue that break/continue are more elegant constructs in terms of readability than goto. The only legitimate case i've ever found for using goto was in switch statements, where you can implement superset/subset logic using 'goto case [label]'.

Comment: @Bradley Smith. No, even then it's bad. Use method calls if you use the same piece of code twice.

Comment: Although this is correct, why do you insist on using `DialogResult.OK`? From the OP's code it seems that he's using WPF, where `ShowDialog` returns a `Nullable<bool>`

Comment: is SaveFileDialog implicitly convertable to `System.IDisposable`? cos i am getting an error saying it not. and yes, i am using WPF

Comment: Okay, my mistake. System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog implements IDisposable, but the WPF version evidently does not.